# How can I after changing selected value in my form call url with GET value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I after changing selected value in my form call url with GET value:

For example: I selected `<option value="dog">Dog</option>` and this url is running:

`www.mysite.com?query=dog`

```
<form>
    <select class="select-box">
        <option name="query" value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option name="query" value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option name="query" value="pig">Pig</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: look at [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Any javascript or jquery that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".select-box").on("change", function() {
    var query = $('.select-box').find(":selected").text();
    $.ajax( ... pass in url and 
        data: {query : query}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".select-box").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "www.mysite.com"
        type: 'get', //a http get request
        data: {
            query: $(this).find("option:selected").val()
        }
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response); //handle response here
        }
    });
});
});
```